# how to restrict assets files to access directly in angular 4

Tags: angular

I have css and other files in assets of angular-cli json in angular 4. want to restrict those files from directly accessing.
Example: "assets": [ source ] that source has example.js file.
www.example.com/example.js - user should not access this directly only my code should access.

Comment: Thats not really possible, as your code will run in the browser and this needs to load assets anyways

Comment: Anything the browser can access, the client can possibly access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I just exported js code and imported in ts files. Also adding allowJs in compiler option resolved my problem.