# Prevent from downloading config.ts file in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am working on angular 6 application and i had query regarding configuration files in angular.

Just like web.config, we can create config.ts file and keep our configuration setting here. but how i prevent from downloading this config.ts file from browser?

I want my angular application to read my configuration file (config.ts) but does not allow any one to download it from url.

example - if user hit this url (**abc.com/assest/config.ts**) on browser then its not allowed him to see/download config.ts file (just like web.config)

or any alternate solution will be appreciated.

you can refer 1 post related to it (but i am not able to understand the solution ) - [how to restrict assets files to access directly in angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48638456/how-to-restrict-assets-files-to-access-directly-in-angular-4)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you expose your file, anyone can read it.

Comment: so how can i achieve this or any other solution which help me.